# Jupyter Notebook Iframe hide menu bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an Iframe of jupyter notebook in my application. I want to hide the menu bar and just show the cells. Is it possible to configure it ? This is how it looks currently

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom javascript and toggle it

```
$('#header').toggle()
$('#menubar').toggle();
```

you can find some reference [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2135)